# Groovy stage not accepting java array list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to reference a list in a groovy stage as below:

```
stage('Post Build Actions') {
  emailext subject: "(Status ${currentBuild.result})", to: (['test1@test.co.uk', 'test2@test.co.uk']), body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT'
}
```

However, this gives the error:

```
class hudson.plugins.emailext.EmailExtStep.setTo() expects class java.lang.String but received class java.util.ArrayList
```

Any ideas if I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  emailext subject: "(Status ${currentBuild.result})", to: 'test1@test.co.uk,test2@test.co.uk', body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT'
```

Ie, just put them in a single string with a comma separating them